# Creating default value for Select/dropdown list and can be selected default value back again manually - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui

I have gone through many sites before posting a question here and to understand on how to create a `defaultValue` in `select` however, all sites talks about setting the value but no where it talks about selecting the default value back again.

**What I need**

I have some 6 dropdown controls that has different values and each dropdown list is filled by API.
now I have used `defaultValue` as **"--Select One--"** for my work, it works as expected, however I need the **default value** to be selected again when needed manually, like if user want to undo the list back to default value**(--Select One--)**.

**Why I need this**

As said before I have 6 dropdown values and imagine I have selected values for 5 dropdown and I want to undo one of the option from any dropdown then the only option I have to `clear` all dropdown lists and do the selection again.

**CODE**

```
<Select className="AdvancedFilterText"
          ref={selectRef}
          options={categoryOptions}
          styles={{
            option: base => ({
              ...base,
              borderBottom: '1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 80%,.5)',
              height: '100%',
            }),
          }}
          defaultValue={{value: "0", label:"--Select One--"}}
          isSearchable
          placeholder={"CHOOSE CATEGORY"}
          onChange={event => onCategorySelect(event)}>
        </Select>
```

Post adding `MenuItem`

[image]

Comment: What is this `Select` component? Material UI, Semantic UI, bootstrap, custom component?

Comment: That's going to be Material UI.

Comment: Could you please provide an illustration?

Comment: @Hamidreza imagine you have list and at the very top you should have default value something like --Select One--, now I can change/select the value to valid selection from the list, now I wanted to make the selection to default value again like ''--Select One--" that I should be able to do it, unfortunately Material UI has option to set `defaultValue` however it doesn't have any option to select the `defaultValue` manually.

let me know if you got what I am saying.+

Answer (score 0):

Set `displayEmpty` and have one option with `value=''`

```js
const data = [
  { value: 'accounting', label: 'Accounting' },
  { value: 'authority', label: 'Authority' },
  { value: 'coverage', label: 'Coverage' },
  { value: 'investigation', label: 'Investigation' }
]; // data from server

<Select displayEmpty>
  <MenuItem value=''>Select...</MenuItem>
  {data.map(item => 
    <MenuItem key={item.value} value={item.value}>
      {item.label} 
    </MenuItem>)
  }
</Select>
```

Comment: Nope, I am still not seeing default entry in the list and cannot select `MenuItem` as you suggested. I just added screenshot for reference. I still don't see default entry to re-select.

Comment: thanks for trying! I had tried this before unfortunately this is not working too, I will create one Sandbox and share the link.

the code you shared may work when you have hardcoded lists, however I am getting dynamic values using API.